# Angular Controller Checks Service Promise to Update View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, undefined, promise

I'm having trouble with angular controllers and services and I can't get them to play well together.

I have Parse API to login and I want the controller to know that a un/successful login took place and update the view accordingly.

I tried returning a boolean from the Parse login promise from the service but the controller cannot see this and when I set a variable equal to the service function I get 'undefined.'

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService){

    $scope.ctrlFunc = function(){           
        var login = userService.login($scope.username, $scope.password);
            //$scope.username & password are defined in other section
        console.log(login); //returns 'undefined'
        if(login == true){
            // go to other function
        }
        else{
            // do $scope changes to view
        }
    };
}]);

app.service ('userService', function(){
    this.login = function(){
        Parse.User.logIn(username, password,{
            success: function (user){
                return true;
            },
            error: function (error){
                return false;
            }
        })
    };
});
```

My controller was bloated with logic so I tried offloading it to a service. Easier said than done for an angular beginner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not taken into consideration the async nature of the login behavior. You either need to use callbacks or use Angular promises to handle login success or failure.

With a promise mechanism the service becomes

```
app.service ('userService', function($q){
    var defer=$q.defer();
    this.login = function(){
        Parse.User.logIn(username, password,{
            success: function (user){
                defer.resolve(true);
            },
            error: function (error){
                defer.reject(false);
            }
        })
        return defer.promise;
    };
});
```

Now in the controller you can do:

```
var login = userService.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
            .then(function(result) { //result will be true and you can react to it.},
                  function(error) { //error will be true and you can react to it.})
```

Read about Angular promises to understand how things work.

Comment: Thank you! Still trying to wrap my head around promises, hasn't clicked for me but this code helps make sense of everything a bit more.

Comment: Maybe this can help you a bit http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 0):

Your userService shouuld return a promise ,

```
this.login = function(){
      return  userService.logIn(username, password)
 };
```

and then in the controller ,

```
 var login =  Parse.User.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function(){
                $scope.isLoggedIn=true;
         }).error(function(){
                 $scope.isLoggedIn=false;
           })
```

And in the Parse.User service it should return a promise ,

```
Parse.User.login=function(username,pwd){
  return  $http.post('/someUrl', {userName:username,password:pwd})
}
```